# Street that intersects itself more than 3 times in one spot

Tags: where-on-earth, locate-this

In Washington DC [Yuma St](https://www.google.com/maps/place/38%C2%B056'46.6%22N+77%C2%B005'58.0%22W/@38.9469897,-77.0999733,18z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d38.946269!4d-77.099435?hl=en) creates a 3 way intersection with itself such that at the intersection you can go 4 ways, three of them are on Yuma St and one is not. I would like to visit the place where a street intersects itself the most times in one place such that when standing in the intersection I can go more than 3 different ways on the same street. If there is no place with more than 3 options is there a place with only 3 options and all are the same street?

Comment: With regard to a junction where all 3 roads have the same name, this is fairly common in the UK (and possibly elsewhere) when there are very small dead end stubs. They often don't get there own name and instead use that of the larger road. Some examples can be seen at: https://goo.gl/maps/5SYyHecjNP82

Comment: That must be hilarious for giving directions. Turn left on Yuma, then left again into Yuma....

Comment: Austria too, and since we have UK already, I'd guess "many European countries".

Comment: Thailand has highways that split into the same number, so at an intersection Hwy 1001 can go three different ways.  I vaguely remember a four way split but can't pin point where I was.

Comment: "Please give me a big list of roads satisfying some amusing criterion. I claim I want to visit these locations, so I can call this a travel question." Voting to close as too broad, but also "[not an actual problem that you face](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)".

Comment: Not sure this is a good question, this seems to be a pretty arbitrary property of the naming scheme (as opposed to there being anything special about the intersections or the streets themselves).

Answer (score 1):

In Quebec both provincial highway 132 and 169 have 3 way intersections with themselves and no other road.